# How to implement GEO-DNS for application routing

Tags: dns, routes, geolocation, ip

**Problem: How to implement GEO-DNS for application routing**

## **Overview**

> I have a 'SAME-DOMAIN.COM'. When a user will visit from Region 1 or 2,
>   I want to identify his region (ie. 1 or 2) and forward him to
>   'SAME-DOMAIN.COM' with IP 123.123.123.123 for Region 1, and if they
>   visit from Region 2, then forward them to the 'SAME-DOMAIN.COM' with
>   IP 456.456.456.456.

*I have 2 Servers:*
- Server 1 (IP): 123.123.123.123
- Server 2 (IP): 456.456.456.456

*I have 1 Domain:*
- SAME-DOMAIN.COM

When a Regional client visits my site, I want to check which region they came from and then send them to the appropriate server to access the Application/Content. So Based on this I have grouped my Clients to 2 Regions as follows:

*Client List:* A, B, C, D, E, F

*Regional Clients*

Region 1: A, B C
Region 2: D, E, F

**Issue:**

> When a visitor from Region 1 comes to my SAME-DOMAIN.COM, How do I
>   Keep the SAME-DOMAIN.COM but forward the user to SERVER 1 (IP:
>   123.123.123.123). And when Visitor from Region 2 visits SAME-DOMAIN.COM, forward the user to SERVER 2 (IP: 456.456.456.456)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Route53 from Amazon.
This service have exactly this feature